# i just want to pass mail from my gmail account in laravel but it generate error

Tags: laravel-5.1

I just want to pass mail from my gmail account  in laravel but it generate errors

```
my code:
Routes.php
Route::get('/sendbasicemai','MailController@basic_email');

i change in .env file as below
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=abx.xyz@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

and in config.php
array (
    'driver' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => '465',
    'from' => 
     array (
      'address' => NULL,
      'name' => NULL,
    ),
    'encryption' => NULL,
    'username' => 'abc.xyz@gmail.com',
    'password' => '*********',
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
    'pretend' => false,
    ),

 MailController.php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mail;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class MailController extends Controller
{
public function basic_email(){
   $data = array('name'=>"Virat Gandhi");

  Mail::send(['text'=>'mail'], $data, function($message) {
     $message->to('abc@xyz.in', 'Tutorials Point')->subject
        ('Laravel Basic Testing Mail');
     $message->from('abc.xyz@gmail.com','Virat Gandhi');
  });
  echo "Basic Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
  }
}

Mail.blade.php 
<h1>Hi, {{ $name }}</h1>
<p>Sending Mail from Laravel.</p>
```

I am new in laravel and I just read this link [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_sending_email.htm)

I just practice as "Tutorial" suggest and I practice in local host

but it generate bunch of errors:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
```

and much more

Comment: pls. click on my link "Tutorial" if anyone could not understand my question.

Comment: Please post your exact errors.